# Как ввести данные в postgresql через драйвер py-postgresql?

Tags: python, flask

Использую библиотеку `Flask`. Как ввести данные в postgresql через драйвер py-postgresql?

Comment: @integr1, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Как один из вариантов:

1. [Настроить Flask на работу с SqlAlchemy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/)
2. [Настроить SqlAlchemy на работу с py-postgresql](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.pypostgresql)
3. [Ввести данные в базу используя SqlAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html#inserting-records)
4. ??????
5. PROFIT!

Comment: Просто нужен пример введа данных в PostgreSQL через Flask.
Py-postgresql - работает.Можно выбирать ORM или py-postgres.